# Installing SSL certificate on nginx server

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ssl-certificate

I am trying to install a positivessl certificate on my server without success. I started creating a mydomain.key file on my server and requested the certificate. I bundled the files using

```
cat www_***_co_uk.crt COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt  COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt > ssl-bundle.crt
```

I uploaded this file to my server to the `home/piet` directory. That's also where my .key and .csr are. Now I need to update the nginx config, right? I am using the drupal droplet installation from digital ocean. In my `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` I have

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr 22 07:38 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Nov 25 18:45 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   16 Apr 22 07:38 default
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   33 Nov 25 18:45 drupal -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/drupal
```

Here the default file is empty so I followed the link.
In  `/etc/nginx/sites-available` I have

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 25 18:45 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Nov 25 18:45 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2709 Apr 22 07:49 default
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1607 Apr 22 08:08 drupal
```

I edited the drupal file to

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
  rewrite ^/(.*) https://www.***.co.uk/$1 permanent;
  root /var/www/html/drupal;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;

  error_page 404 /404.html;
  error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html {
      root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }

  location = /favicon.ico {
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
   }

   location = /robots.txt {
     allow all;
     log_not_found off;
     access_log off;
   }

   location ~ \..*/.*\.php$ {
     return 403;
   }
   location ~ ^/sites/.*/private/ {
     return 403;
   }

   location ~ (^|/)\. {
     return 403;
   }

   location / {
     try_files $uri @rewrite;
   }

   location @rewrite {
     rewrite ^ /index.php;
   }

   location ~ \.php$ {
     fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
     include fastcgi_params;
         fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
     fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
     fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
   }

   location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/styles/ {
     try_files $uri @rewrite;
   }

   location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
     expires max;
     log_not_found off;
   }
}
server {


    listen 443;
    server_name www.***.co.uk;

    root /var/www/html/drupal;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /home/piet/ssl-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/piet/www.***.co.uk.key;

    ssl_session_timeout 5m;

    ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers "HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5 or HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!3DES";
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;


}
```

But it still does not seem to work. In fact I expected at least to redirect the `http://` site to `https://` but even that is not the case. I did restart nginx after every edit. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `In fact I expected at least to redirect the http:// site to https:// but even that is not the case` are you connecting to this server at all? The http->https redirect you have `rewrite ^/(.*) https://www.***.co.uk/$1 permanent;` would capture all requests. Though that's not [the best way to do it](https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-nginx/blob/master/sites-available/ssl.example.com#L13). Note that all your location blocks are in the wrong server block, if your intention is to be https only.

Answer (score 2):

All of your location blocks need to be in the https server block since that's what is handling your requests. The only logic that needs to be in the http server section is what's required to perform the redirect.

**Edit:**
Now that we have the hostname in question, I can see that port 443 on your server is closed:

```
$ nmap www.boilerplaza.co.uk -p 443

Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-04-22 09:12 CDT
Nmap scan report for www.boilerplaza.co.uk (46.101.22.233)
Host is up (0.10s latency).
PORT    STATE  SERVICE
443/tcp closed https

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.36 seconds
```

Perhaps you need to open that port in your firewall.

Comment: okay thanks, i'll try that! Would that then solve the problem?

Comment: Right now, if I type https://www.***.co.uk in my browser it says "server not found".

Comment: Please give us the domain you're working on.

Comment: www.boilerplaza.co.uk

Comment: @user1043065 Please see my edit above.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any clue one how to open it? I ran `sudo ufw allow 443/tcp` and restarted ufw (`sudo ufw disable` `sudo ufw enable`) which did not seem to help. I did not restart the server. However when I ran the first line it said `Skipping adding existing rule` and I recall that I opened 443 also at system configuration. Still 443 remains closed. Btw I moved the server to ip http://46.101.4.219.

Comment: I have also tried `sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT` which also does not seem to help...

Comment: Your site works fine. So, it was likely the DNS propagation issue. You may want to mark @EEAA's answer as the correct answer, since it helped you.